# Divs as page like in Google Docs and split content pasted?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, google-docs

In google docs, when we paste lot of data it automatically splits it into pages which are printer friendly, How can I build this basic google docs type functionality. *The source of data will be fetched from database instead of paste.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could gradually fill a div with text using JavaScript. Check the height after each word and after reaching a certain height (e.g. ~25cm for DIN A 4) insert a new paragraph tag with `page-break-before: always` to break the page in the print.